# 403 GIven When Changing Nginx Root Directory

Tags: nginx, fedora

Using Fedora 33, I am trying to instruct nginx to serve content from a different directory other than `/usr/share/nginx/html`.

Changing `root /usr/share/nginx/html` to `root /home/william/Documents/testserve` results in a HTTP 403. Many sites suggest permissions is an issue, but after changing the mode of the folder and its contents to 777, and changing ownership to nginx - I'm fairly certain it's not. I have also temporarily disabled selinux to see if selinux policies were an issue.

Restoring the default configuration and creating `localhost.conf` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d` has also proven ineffective. How am I able to instruct nginx to serve content from a different directory?

```
# /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

```
# /etc/nginx/conf.d/localhost.conf
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        root /home/william/Documents/testserve;
        index index.php index.html;
}
```

Comment: Check the nginx error log, it will tell you if there is a permission issue.

Comment: Every directory in the path needs to be readable by the process running the Nginx server.

Comment: @rauberdaniel It has written "/home/william/Documents/testserve/index.php" is forbidden (13: Permission denied). I don't see how nginx doesn't have permission since I have given ownership of this file to nginx.

Answer (score 3):

I kinda had the same problem, and it took me 10+ hours to solve it. I don't know if this is the solution to your problem in this case, but to anyone, that encounters the **403** problem on fedora, there is something that is called **SeLinux** (security enforced) and it might be blocking the access to files, even if the permissons are correct.

You can check if its enabled with :

`getenforce`
(enforcing = turned on)

and turn it on and off with:

`setenforce 0` (or 1 depending on what you want)

If it works with Selinux turned off, you can fix the problem with:

`sudo chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/website.com`

hope that helps anyone

Comment: This works like a charm! BTW, the `-R` option in second `chcon` command is optional, and for more details about SELinux check [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-maintaining_selinux_labels_-checking_the_default_selinux_context)

Answer (score -1):

Check if all directories are root user, that works for me.